# Allow user to input certain value in locked cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working with two pieces of vba code. I am trying to marry them together to achieve the below purpose.

**First code**

I have code that allows users to double click on a cell and then it time stamps the cell, and subsequently locks the  relevant cell.  Which works fine. However is some instances the user will have to **type in NA** and different piece of code will run ( Second code).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target
        If .Column = 4 Then
            Select Case .Row
                Case 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65
                Sheets("Sheet3").Protect Password:="Test", userinterfaceonly:=True
                    .Value2 = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username")
                    .Value2 = .Value2 & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
                     .Locked = True
                    End Select
                 End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Second Code when user Types NA**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    '// Check if the target row number is in our array:
    Select Case Target.Row
        Case 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65
            ' Do Something
            If CStr(Target.Value) Like "*NA*" Then

                Target.Value = "Not applicable" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

            End If

        Case Else
            ' Do nothing
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

**Problem to Overcome**

Once the user double clicks on a the cell and it locks , there are not able to later change that cell to NA. NA should be the only value that the user should be able to type once cell is locked.

**Question**

Is there a way that i can allow the user to type in NA only once the cell is locked. Therefore user only has  two options to type **na or Double click**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can't type anything until a cell is locked. Add data validation to allow "NA" only instead of locking the cell. Something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Target
        If .Column = 4 Then
            Select Case .Row
                Case 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65
                    .Value2 = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
                    With .Validation
                        .Delete
                        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="NA"
                        .IgnoreBlank = False
                        .InCellDropdown = False
                        .ErrorTitle = "Invalid input"
                        .ErrorMessage = "NA available only"
                        .ShowError = True
                    End With
           End Select
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This method assumes that the worksheet isn't protected at all.

Comment: A novel solution!  (I think validation would still allow a non "NA" value to be **copied** into the cell though, but it might be sufficient for the OP's purposes.)  But ... (a) the code won't run for me while the sheet is protected (despite it being protected for `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`!), it crashes trying to add the validation (b) you will need to ensure that, once the sheet is protected, that cell will need to be left unlocked (i.e. `.Locked = False`?) so that the user can actually enter the "NA" if needed.  So I suspect you don't need, or want, the sheet protection at all.

Comment: @omegastripes Thanks for that. The updated answer work  perfect

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for the assistance